# Problema al renderizar vista (react-router 1.0) componente indefinido

Tags: reactjs

No puedo renderizar la vista, mi código es como el siguiente ejemplo 
[server](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md).

Cuando corro el servidor:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

{ [Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.] name: 'Invariant Violation', framesToPop: 1 }
```

Y esto me muestra cuando le hago un log a `renderProps`:

```
{ routes: 
   [ { childRoutes: [Object] },
     { path: '/',
       component: [Function: BaseAdmin],
       indexRoute: [Object],
       childRoutes: [Object] },
     { component: [Function: Home] } ],
  params: {},
  location: 
   { pathname: '/',
     search: '',
     hash: '',
     state: null,
     action: 'POP',
     key: 'zljum4',
     query: {},
     '$searchBase': { search: '', searchBase: '' } },
  components: [ undefined, [Function: BaseAdmin], [Function: Home] ],
  history: 
   { listenBefore: [Function: listenBefore],
     listen: [Function: listen],
     transitionTo: [Function: transitionTo],
     push: [Function: push],
     replace: [Function: replace],
     go: [Function: go],
     goBack: [Function: goBack],
     goForward: [Function: goForward],
     createKey: [Function: createKey],
     createPath: [Function: createPath],
     createHref: [Function: createHref],
     createLocation: [Function: createLocation],
     setState: [Function: setState],
     registerTransitionHook: [Function: registerTransitionHook],
     unregisterTransitionHook: [Function: unregisterTransitionHook],
     pushState: [Function: pushState],
     replaceState: [Function: replaceState],
     isActive: [Function: isActive],
     match: [Function: match],
     listenBeforeLeavingRoute: [Function: listenBeforeLeavingRoute] } }
```

Comment: Creo que si pusieras el código que utilizas para hacer el `render` serviria para darnos una mejor idea de que pasa.

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver el código del componente será difícil ayudarte, pero lo más probable es que no lo estés exportando correctamente.
Si el componente está en un archivo .js aparte asegurate de que lo exportas correctamente:

En ES6 sería así:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default MyComponent
```